# lines repeat in List python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, count

I need your help with the next problem,
i need that a python recieve an string "EEEEDDSGES" and the output would by the sum of charactes that repeat in line,
E 4
D 2
S 1
G 1
E 1
S 1

my code is the next,

````
diccionario = {}
contador = 0
for palabra in cadena:

    if palabra.upper() in diccionario:
        diccionario[palabra.upper()] += 1
    else:
        diccionario[palabra.upper()] = 1
for palabra in diccionario:
    frecuencia = diccionario[palabra]
    print(palabra, end=" ")
    print(frecuencia) ```

the output is ,

S,S,d,f,s
S 1
S 2
d 3
f 4
s 5
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
from itertools import groupby

s = "EEEEDDSGES"

for v, g in groupby(s):
    print(v, sum(1 for _ in g))
```

Prints:

```
E 4
D 2
S 1
G 1
E 1
S 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I don't understand what this language is, but I guess I understand what you are trying to do. I have changed the variable names for my comprehension.

```
s="EEEEDDSGES"

letters={}

for i in s:
  i=i.upper()
  try:
    letters[i]+=1
  except(KeyError):
    letters.update({i:1})
    
for i in letters: print(f"{i}: {letters[i]}", end=" ")
```